# Eclipse Maven Spring HibernateEntityManage: Mission artifact sprinframework: spring-core

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

I am newbie to SpringFramework.
I created a test project worked perfect in eclipse wit Maven and with dependency spring-core.

I want to use MySQL, so i used hibernate related dependencies. As I got to know, hibernate-entitymanage is better han  use hibernate core.

Here is details of pom.xml

```
    <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
<hibernate.entitymanager.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.entitymanager.version>
    <hibernate.validator.version>5.1.3.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
</properties>

    <!-- junit for testing  -->  
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>{hibernate.entitymanager.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
     </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I get following error

> ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:{hibernate.entitymanager.version}:
>   ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:pom:{hibernate.entitymanager.version}
>   from/to central repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Illegal
>   character in path at index 74:
>   repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/{hibernate.entitymanager.version}/hibernate-entitymanager-{hibernate.entitymanager.version}.pom

I can't post the screen capture of eclipse :(

For past two days i have searched enough in net and tried every possibilities.

#### A Few notable things:

1. deleted all contents in .m2/repository and start eclipse again
2. Clean the project and build again
3. Moving "Maven Project Builder" to top in the 'Builders' list in Project Properties
4. Project Properties -> Maven -> Update Project
5. including Jboss repo in pom.xml file (repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/) in repository tag

But cant get a break through :(

### My Objective :

To develop/learn Application with Eclipse(using Luna) + SpringMVC + Hibernate EntityManager + MySql + Bootstrap

- Pom.xml file is giving problem as explained above.

### I am looking for solutions to:

1. missing artifacts error for above pom .
2. Is it possible to add more one or more repository in Pom file. in case how to mention specific jar to be retrieved from that particular repository
3. In one of a question/answer thread, some one mentioned to jboss repository. what is difference between Maven and Jboss repository. which is better to use and how to configure maven for the same.
4. I am seeing jars alread downloaded under Maven Dependency, still i get 'Missing artifacts' on those jars..

Wish some one guide me.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well i am a bit surprised (i dont have time to verify it right now) but you cant solve the error on your side since the Spring version you are using seems to populate a incorrect `pom.xml` file (surprised since it is the release version...).

Comment: Have you tried with an older version like 4.3.7?

Comment: Missing `$` in front of `{hibernate.entitymanager.version}` in the `<version>` tag for the entitymanager.

Comment: How silly I am :(  Thanks Deinum, you got a great eye !
Now there is no error on pom.xml But getting red x mark (error mark ) in Java Resources folder, and not seeing any error mark in files.. strange!

Can I go ahead with default maven repository, hope there is no difference between maven and jboss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1:** You have a syntax error in the pom file. As @M.Deinum stated in the comments:

> Missing `$` in front of `{hibernate.entitymanager.version}` in the `<version>` tag for the entitymanager.

**Answer 2:** I haven't tried this but according to the [Maven Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories), `<repositories>` is a collection so you may be able to define more than one repository as a backup. Here the documentation refers to multiple alternate repositories.

> If that artifact does not exist in the local repository, it will then attempt to download from a remote repository. The repository elements within a POM specify those alternate repositories to search.

**Answer 3:** JBoss has some documentation on their developer wiki about the [Maven Repository](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/MavenRepository?_sscc=t) that may better explain their repository for JBoss developers. This includes information on their proxied repositories. I think you should be fine using the default Maven repository though.

> This page provides information about the JBoss.org Maven repositories
>   hosted on repository.jboss.org.  The JBoss.org Maven repositories are
>   managed by Nexus, and are available to all members of the JBoss
>   community.  Depending on the needs of your project, you can choose to
>   configure your  Maven settings using one or more of the individual
>   repository URLs, or you can choose to use a combined repository view
>   via the group URLs.

**Answer 4:** This sounds like a problem with how your IDE is set up. You may need to set it to check the Maven Dependency directory.